# Loop through a character in sql

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, charindex

```
DECLARE @valueList varchar(8000)
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

SET @valueList = '00000129563698'

set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX('0', @valueList, @pos+1)<>0
BEGIN
    set @len = CHARINDEX('0', @valueList, @pos+1) - @pos
    set @value = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos, @len)

    PRINT @value

    set @pos = CHARINDEX('0', @valueList, @pos+@len) +1
END
```

I want to remove the zeros from `@valueList` variable and store the remaining part in another variable.

How can I do this in sql?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in a single statement, i.e. without a WHILE loop?

Comment: yes any possibility is fine. but @valueList = '0000022956497698' this will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function to look for the first non-zero digit;

```
DECLARE @valueList varchar(8000)

SET @valueList = '00000129563698'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@valueList, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @valueList), 8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
declare @orig varchar(100)
set @orig='00000129563698'

declare @dup varchar(100)


set @dup= REPLACE(@orig,'0','')

select @dup
```

### [Demo To replace all zero's](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1331)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to numeric and convert to string again.

```
SET @valueList = convert(varchar,(convert(int,'00000129563698')))
```

Comment: @VijayPV, what about zero inside? Just like `'000000120244562007'`

Comment: inside zero should not replace. anyway i got the answer for this, thanks for       your valuable time spend for this